# Hadoop version 1 vs version 2 performance

Tags: performance, hadoop, bigdata

I am planning to update from Hadoop version 1 to Hadoop version 2. Can anyone please tell me (if you have tried hadoop version 2), is there any performance improvement of MR /Hive/Pig jobs in version 2 over version 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the notes from [apache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/). These are the highlights of the improvements.

Here is a short overview of the improvments to both HDFS and MapReduce.

HDFS Federation
In order to scale the name service horizontally, federation uses multiple independent Namenodes/Namespaces. The Namenodes are federated, that is, the Namenodes are independent and don't require coordination with each other. The datanodes are used as common storage for blocks by all the Namenodes. Each datanode registers with all the Namenodes in the cluster. Datanodes send periodic heartbeats and block reports and handles commands from the Namenodes.

More details are available in the HDFS Federation document.

MapReduce NextGen aka YARN aka MRv2
The new architecture introduced in hadoop-0.23, divides the two major functions of the JobTracker: resource management and job life-cycle management into separate components.

The new ResourceManager manages the global assignment of compute resources to applications and the per-application ApplicationMaster manages the application‚Äôs scheduling and coordination.

An application is either a single job in the sense of classic MapReduce jobs or a DAG of such jobs.

The ResourceManager and per-machine NodeManager daemon, which manages the user processes on that machine, form the computation fabric.

The per-application ApplicationMaster is, in effect, a framework specific library and is tasked with negotiating resources from the ResourceManager and working with the NodeManager(s) to execute and monitor the tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've read Hadoop v2 release notes and found out the new features like YARN, MR2 and other architectural changes. All i need to know if someone compared any MR/Hive/PIG jobs on v2 against v1 and found out any performance improvements.